# view Recording in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any library to record activity of a particular `UIView` ( I came across this lib [`ASScreenRecorder`-master] but its showing many errors when I tried to use it in swift ) or any other way to record the `UIView` which is displaying some animation like falling snow and slide show of the images? I want them to get recorded as a single video and to save them to the gallery. I have looked around for the some solutions but i am still unable to record the view. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
func start() {
    let sharedRecorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

    // Do nothing if screen recording is not available
    guard sharedRecorder.isAvailable else { return }

    // Stop previous recording if necessary
    if sharedRecorder.isRecording {
        stopScreenRecording()
    }

    print("Starting screen recording")

    // Register as the recorder's delegate to handle errors.
    sharedRecorder.delegate = self

    // Start recording
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        #if os(iOS)
            sharedRecorder.isMicrophoneEnabled = true
            //sharedRecorder.isCameraEnabled = true // fixme
        #endif

        sharedRecorder.startRecording { [unowned self] error in
            if let error = error as? NSError, error.code != RPRecordingErrorCode.userDeclined.rawValue {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                // Show alert
                return
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        sharedRecorder.startRecording(withMicrophoneEnabled: true) { error in
            if let error = error as? NSError, error.code != RPRecordingErrorCode.userDeclined.rawValue {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                // Show alert
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try `ASScreenRecorder` but i think it might be your best option so show what is the error, or check [cocoapods search](https://cocoapods.org/?q=screen%20record)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got a solution to record the screen and that is using Replay Kit but the problem is that it records the entire screen but what  i want is to record a particular view activity , Can you please help me with this , Here is the code:

Comment: @SwiftyCodes   Have a look at this https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: No Sir, That doesn't helps as the big problem is that i know only swift so I am looking for a solution in swift. Any other help that you can provide sir..

Comment: I have found another library that does the same but its not recording the content that is being displayed on the view, Its shows black as a background but yeah it does make a video when i Start and Stop the recording , Can Anyone please help me out . The lib that I used is --> https://github.com/adam-roth/screen-cap-view. In the documentation it says that i just need to pass the View that i want to record and i do the same but the content that is displayed on it does not saves . Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "i know only swift so I am looking for a solution in swift."

What kind of a nonsense is this? What does the language has to do with anything in this question? You have a framework question, and you have been provided with a framework answer, which you shoot down because you are too lazy to try to read ObjC? This is a terrible approach to development.

Comment: It's an off-topic question as well - asking for a Third Party library recommendations. Unfortunately, as there is a bounty on it it can't be closed yet.

Comment: Why down vote it? It is a good question. You can record the whole screen with ReplayKit, but unfortunately there is no way to record only the view.

Comment: Yeah ! I don't get it why people are down voting this question . I have tried some of the approaches to it like replay kit and all and tried some objective C libraries to but didn't get the solution to it . And for a solution i used that Bounty thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot currently record a particular UIView. You can record the entire screen with ReplayKit, however I understand that was not what you were looking for.

**Other ideas:**

Record the "entire screen" but try to crop to the UIView. (see [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos)). Think of a way in your app where it would make sense to record the entire screen- maybe expand the UIView to the screen boundaries.

Try looking at some of these Github files:

> [File1](https://github.com/wess/Glimpse)
>
> [File2](https://github.com/adam-roth/screen-cap-view)
>
> [File3](https://github.com/andydrizen/UIViewRecorder)

Comment: This is really the only way to go without jailbreaking the device. +1

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. Though it didn't help me fully but it still helped me out to some extent. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah sure tag me in other questions if u need any other help

Comment: Ok sure , Thanks :)

Comment: can somebudy please tell me i have use the Recorder() class and succfully to get the frames please let me know how to save it in video
?