# How to record uiview animation

Tags: swift, uiview, gradient, uiviewanimation, cagradientlayer

I am doing project in which i have to use gradient animation but and i want to record that animation video for 30 seconds,

I have used gradient animation using CAGradientLayer
https://medium.com/@rwbutler/animated-gradients-on-ios-aa117551e533.

I have used glimpse other third party apps but that are not recoding more than 5 seconds.
https://github.com/wess/Glimpse

I have UIView as background view and i want to record video.

Comment: Did you try [flipbook](https://github.com/bgayman/FlipBook)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [view Recording in iOS swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583997/view-recording-in-ios-swift)

Comment: @DamiaanDufaux yes tried flipbook but can't reduce fps , so when i record video it reaches out of memory.